# Probability of sighting the tiger

Tags: probability

Question is: You are at Ranthambore National Park where the probability of sighting a tiger is $95\%$ in every day trip i.e. $8$ hours long. What is the probability that you will see a tiger in a half day trip i.e. $4$ hours long?

*Though it seemed quite easy at first, I'm not able to get my head around this one. I think it should be above $60\%-70\%$ at least but not sure how to approach the solution to such a of problem.*

Comment: Well, you need a model of some sort.  Poisson seems good for something like this...what $8$ hour mean would give you a probability of $.95$?

Comment: Just to be clear:  you really do need a model.  To take an extreme model, suppose that the tiger is onsite with probability $.95$ on a given day and is otherwise off somewhere else, and that you are guaranteed to see him immediately if he is onsite.  Then the four hour answer is the same as the eight hour answer.

Comment: Or what if after smelling you for eight hours, he just can't resist having a shot, but he's willing to ignore you for four hours?

Comment: @lulu As I understand it, you advise tiger "poissoning".

Comment: @JeanMarie  Maybe tiger fishing?  Sort of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a two day period, the probability of not seeing a tiger on a particular day is .05, so the probability of not seeing a tiger either day is .05^2. So taking a half day, we should go the other way, and take the square root. So the probability of not seeing a tiger in a four hour period is $\sqrt{.05}$ = 22.4%, and the probability of seeing a tiger is 77.6%.

Comment: Yeah, this is it, I guess.